# Laravel 4 custom validation - [method] does not exist

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to implement and use a couple of my own custom validation methods in a class called `WBValidation` that extends `Illuminate\Validation\Validator`

I have this method `validateCombinedRequired`:

```
 class WBValidation extends Illuminate\Validation\Validator{


     public function validateCombinedRequired($attribute,$value,$parameters){
            return (    $this->validateRequired($attribute,$value)  )
            and    (    $this->validateRequired($parameters[0],$this->data[$parameters[0]])     );
        }
}
```

I have placed this class in the libraries folder. For the framework to automatically pick up this class, it might be getting picked up because I can see it in `autoload_classmap.php`  ( I might be wrong ).

When I try to use it in my model, I am getting this error which says `BadMethodCallException","message":"Method [validateCombinedRequired] does not exist`:

```
class UserModel extends Eloquent{
    protected $table='user';
    public static function VerifyUserAdd($data){


        $rules = array('password'=>'required|combined_required:repassword');

        // stuff

        return Validator::make($data,$rules,$errormessages);
    }
}
```

Is there anything else I should be doing? Please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to register your custom Validator extension:

```
Validator::resolver(function($translator, $data, $rules, $messages)
{
    return new WBValidation($translator, $data, $rules, $messages);
});
```

I suggest reading the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules) as it covers several was of adding your own custom validation rules.

Comment: You could do it in your `start/global.php`.

Comment: Awesome, that worked. By the way, is there a neater way to do custom validation, besides `validator:extend({});`?